# generate url based on string with regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to generate a URL based on a string in JS with regex

original strings

```
1. (user: john) 
2. (user: mary)
```

expected urls

```
1. http://www.test.com/john
2. http://www.test.com/mary
```

basically everything after : and before) will be the username

Comment: terrible now, but with patience and determination of learning, you can be a master like the other programmers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/\(user: (\w+)\)/g
```

To match the username and store that in the group `$1`. Then you can use `.replace` to replace the rest of the text with your desired URL and use the matched group `$1` at the end of the string.

See example below:

```js
const strs = ["1. (user: john)", "2. (user: mary)"],

res = strs.map(str => str.replace(/\(user: (\w+)\)/g, 'http://www.test.com/$1'));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: i was able to get the group but what was missing was the replace part. now everything works. thank you Nick!

Comment: @handsome No worries!

Comment: You would only be getting that error if `str` wasn't a string... However, to get only the group from the expression you can use `/\(user: (\w+)\)/g.exec("1. (user: john)")[1]`. In this case you will get `"john"`